# Promising an async function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have an array of objects that I'm looping over and calling a function with them as the argument. It's an async/await function, and I'd like to create a  PromiseAll that resolves when all of the async/await calls have concluded. I've used an array map to convert them to promises, but the promises resolve instantly and don't wait until all await calls have been made.

```
async function runTest({_id, name, live, dev}) {
  (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    try {
     const page = await browser.newPage();

    } catch(error) {

     await browser.close()

    } finally {
     await browser.close()
     return
    }
   })();
}

module.exports = (tests) => {
  let testPromises = tests.map((test) =>  {
    return runTest(test).then(function (res) {
      return console.log(res, 'done')
    })
  });

  Promise.all(testPromises).then((data) => {
    console.log('Done resolving')
  }).catch(function(err){
  })
}
```

What is the correct way to guarantee that all of the array objects have passed through the function and completed processing before resolving the PromiseAll? I'm not hugely familiar with async/await.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to call *then* in your mapping based on the documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Are you missing a return statement in the runTest function?

Comment: @sctskw Same issue with or without.

Comment: @Hatchet I do, I've updated the example.

Comment: I take it everything you `await` is returning a `promise`?

Comment: @JamesIves You're still not returning the result of the anonymous async function you're calling in runTest.

Comment: You dont need anonymous async function

Comment: Yeah, no need for that IIFE at all

Comment: @JamesIves yes confused why you have a self-invoking function being called inside your runTest. This is more or less redundant and could very well be conflicting with how your async functions are being run.

Comment: I'm not sure either honestly. I'll be sure to make that change. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need an async IIFE as i already mentioned in comments. More over your code can be simplified like so:

```
async function runTest({_id, name, live, dev}) {
  // we can have one try/catch since you close browser at any error
  try{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
  }
  catch(error) {
    return await browser.close()
  }
}

module.exports = async (tests) => {
  try{
    const data = await Promise.all(tests.map(test => runTest(test)));
    console.log('Done resolving')
  }
  catch(e){ console.log(e)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing a return statement in runTest, though I don't know why you need the anonymous async function in the first place, like @TheReason mentioned:

```
async function runTest({
    _id,
    name,
    live,
    dev
}) {
    return (async () => { // here
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        try {
            const page = await browser.newPage();

        } catch (error) {

            await browser.close()

        } finally {
            await browser.close()
            return
        }
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward approach:

```
function launch() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000, 'blast off!')
  })
}

async function doSomething(id) {
  const message = await launch()
  return `${message} [${id}]`
}


let runs = [10, 20, 30].map(doSomething)

Promise.all(runs).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values)
})

//outputs
[ 'blast off! [10]', 'blast off! [20]', 'blast off! [30]' ]
```